# How to escape curly braces in dwoo?

Tags: google-analytics, dwoo

When I try to insert a Google Analtics tracking code into my dwoo template

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

I get a

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Dwoo\Exception\CompilationException' with
message 'Compilation error at line 25 in "file:templates/template.html"
```

which is in my analytics code (line 25 is the first line starting with `(function(...`). I assume this is due to curly braces. Is there something like `{% raw %}` as in Twig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found it out, you have to escape code like that into `{"..."}`:

```
  {"(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');"}
```

[See documentation: Dwoo for Designers, HTML Escaping](https://github.com/emulienfou/dwoo/wiki/Dwoo-for-Designers#html-escaping).